# self-signed applet running in windows,but not in linux

Tags: java, linux, applet

I have developed an applet, and self-signed it. It is perfectly working on all the browsers on windows machines, but when i try to run it on linux, it shows the following error:
**"your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running"**.
I need to deploy this applet to several machines,on whom I don't have any control.
Plz help me and tell me how to do it free. Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The new security panel of Java deines the security level as High by default, which means you can't run unsigned or self-signed apps **on older versions of Java**.

[image: Java security panel]

My bet is that you are running an older version in your Linux distro.

If you are running Applets, it is wise to alert your users to keep their Java updated to the latest version.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply sir. I am using the latest version of java. java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)